# Using TestFlightApp for a large local distribution of beta testers

Tags: ios, testflight

Does TestFlightApp have any limitations on the number of users or any rate limits? I am thinking of using it to distribute a beta-version app to a crowd at a large conference.

Would testappflight work for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight itself has no such limits. However, if you want to distribute outside of the app store, you'll have to add the device identifiers as approved devices on your account, and you're limited to 100 devices per year.

So there is a limit, and it probably won't work. But the limitation comes from Apple, not from TestFlight.

Comment: I had thought testflight handles the device identifiers?

Comment: TestFlight helps you *gather* the device identifiers, but you still need to add those identifiers to the provisioning portal and include a provisioning profile that authorizes those device identifiers to run the app. That's still all done through Apple.